# Fingerprint scanner works for lock screen but not initial login

Tags: lenovo, 19.04, fingerprint-reader

I have a Lenovo W520 that I recently installed Disco Dingo on. Everything seems to work great, including the fingerprint scanner, with one minor annoyance: I can't login with the fingerprint scanner from the initial login screen. I *can* login from the lock screen with the fingerprint scanner, but when I try to utilize the fingerprint scanner for the initial login screen, it seems to attempt to log me in (the blinking light on the scanner goes out as normal - it will blink rapidly if the fingerprint wasn't recognized), the login screen disappears and appears to log me in, but then it just loops back to the main login screen again.

If I enter my password, it works fine.

Comment: At login, the fingerprint reader wont open the keyring, so mabe someone decided to make that fatal -- check the pam setup for login.

Comment: @ubfan1 Thanks for the information. Do you know where I'd go to look for this setting? My libpam-fu is pretty rusty at the moment. :)

Comment: I'd guess /etc/pam.d/gdm-fingerprint would be the place to start.  I gave up on fingerprint reading on my W520 years ago  when I realized the password was what was used to decode the keyring, so I'd be typing in the login password anyway to read my mail, etc.